# creating array object on each loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, plugins

I'm trying to create an ddData object for each element with id #user, but for some reason it is just displaying the last object.

### This is my js:

```
var count = $('*#user').length;
ddData = [];
i = 1;
$.each($('*#user'), function () {
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        $names = $(this).html();
        ddData = [{
            text: $names,
            value: i++,
            imageSrc: "images/usuari.png"
        }];

        console.log($names);
    }
});

$('#usuarisLlista').ddslick({
    data: ddData,
    width: "200px",
    imagePosition: "left",
    selectText: "Selecciona un usuari"

});
```

So the console.log(names) output the 3 elements there are (the number of elements can be increased so it can't be a fixed number):

[image]

But, it is only displaying the last one:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I am not doing the loop properly? I've tried to find the solution, and I've found in older posts I can use push(), but I can not understand where to add it in my code :S

Thank you!

Comment: be careful creating global variables in loops .... should be `var $names = $(this).html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `push` to add new elements in the array

```
ddData.push({
    text: $names,
    value: i++,
    imageSrc: "images/usuari.png"
});
```

When

```
ddData = [{
    text: $names,
    value: i++,
    imageSrc: "images/usuari.png"
}];
```

is used, the variable will be reinitialized with the value assigned. So, after loop, only the last element will be present in the array.

One more thing is that the selector to select the element with id `user` is incorrect.

```
var count = $('*#user').length; // Remove * from this
```

---

The code contains duplicate ids. ID should be unique, use class instead of id.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5vr78nm6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var ddData = [];
  var i = 0;
  $.each($('.user'), function() {
    var names = $(this).html();
    ddData.push({
      text: names,
      value: i++,
      imageSrc: "images/usuari.png"
    });
    console.log(names);
  });

  $('#userList').ddslick({
    data: ddData,
    width: "200px",
    imagePosition: "left",
    selectText: "Select a user"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ddslick/2.0/jquery.ddslick.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="user">Evelia Molina</td>
    <td class="user">Andy Gon</td>
    <td class="user">Berta Belgrat</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="userList"></div>
```

Comment: aaah!!! I didn't know I didn't need the equal! I was trying to add push before the equal like ddData.push() and I was just having errors and more errors! Well, now, it seems it wants to display multiple values, but instead, it's empty :S

Comment: @eve_mf Check the update in the answer, remove * from the selector and check if this works

Comment: but if I remove this * from the selector it only selects the first element with #user id :S and in the console.log now only appears the first one :S
I'm ussing ddSlick (jquery plugin), I am trying to add it in a jsfiddle, give me a second that I'm quiet bad....

Comment: @eve_mf _but if I remove this * from the selector it only selects the first element with #user id_, that means there are multiple elements with same id, ID should be **unique**. If this is the case, use a class on all the same elements and class selector in JS, `$('.className')`

Comment: I have added it here: http://jsfiddle.net/q9o7q6pc/
You can check, if I delete * from the selector, it only selects the first one :S (I know, it must mean I've done it wrong but I don't understand why only selects the first one otherwise.

Mention that the real table is generated through the database, so I've just made a sample table.

Comment: even if the elements are generated through an array I should have a unique ID? I knew that for html/css but I didn't know it is in all cases! Thank you, actually I've seen now in the jsfiddle it repeats the first one

Comment: @eve_mf Check answer, added working demo at the bottom of answer, you were adding an array like this `.push([{` which should be like `.push({`, without **[**