# I want to create Object-type array，for loop only push last value，why？

Tags: javascript

I want to create Object-type array，for loop only push last value??

```js
  var arr=[];
  var k={};
  k.num=0;
  k.name='';
  a=[1,2,3,4];
  b=['tom','sun','bob','kiki'];
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
      k.num=a[i];
      k.name=b[i];
      arr.push(k)
  }
  console.log(arr)
  
  //result [{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4}]
```

result:

Comment: You're pushing the same object reference 4 times and changing the value of its properties each iteration. Move the creation of the object inside the for loop and it'll work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating array object on each loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240191/creating-array-object-on-each-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Description

Added via comments in code

```js
var arr = [];
// removed object declaration
// removed initialization
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
b = ['tom', 'sun', 'bob', 'kiki'];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  // initialize new object
  var k = {};
  // set properties
  k.num = a[i];
  k.name = b[i];
  arr.push(k)
}
console.log(arr)

//result [{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4}]
```

### Another way

```js
var arr = [];
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
b = ['tom', 'sun', 'bob', 'kiki'];
for (var i = 0, length = a.length; i < length; i++) {
  arr.push({num: a[i], name: b[i]})
}
console.log(arr)

//result [{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4},{name:'kiki',num:4}]
```